# How to send image between Windows Phone app and Windows client app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, http

I am trying to send an image from one device to another over the internet.

The general idea behind it seems simple. I have a jpg file to which I have a path `string path = @"C:\image.jpg` and I would like to send it through web to Windows Phone device (it uses .NET) and receive it in that phone as an object.

Sender is **WPF application**.

Receiver is **Windows Phone 8 device.**

**Digression**
I have done nearly working code for that case using TCP but there is a problem in method posted below. The `BitmapImage` is not available on the WindowsPhone side(receiver) so the object cannot be correctly reconstructed from bytes on the receiver side.

- No, I cannot use WPF Image class because I will get cross threaded
  exception.
- No, I cannot do `Dispatcher.Invoke()` cause Dispatcher is not available at this place.

**These are reasons why I didn't want to post my previous solution. I did not want discussion go offtopic.**

```
private void sendResponse(string path) {
    try {

        BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@path, UriKind.Relative));
        byte[] data;
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmi));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            encoder.Save(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }

        clientStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    } catch (Exception e) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e); }
}
```

**End of digression**

***Question***

**Because of that I do not want to use TCP and ask somebody to provide how to use http to send image from the file to the receiver.**

Comment: You need more tags/ different tags/ more descriptive tags, this is not a wpf question. And you need more detail as well..

Comment: @Akane What additional details do readers need to know?

Comment: HTTP is based upon TCP. I'm guessing you're getting an exception using the Image class because you are not using the dispatcher. Are you sure you cannot call `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke()` ? Or if you use MVVM, you can have the VM call the Dispatcher instead.

Comment: Otherwise, there is a similar topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724843/wpf-loading-serialized-image

Comment: @gretro UDP is connection-less protocol. I know that HTTP use TCP, but I asked for HTTP solution because I would like to get as simple as it gets example. TCP connection looks horrible(I've done that). If you know how send JPG using simple HTTP please show. I cannot call `....Invoke()`, the code is running in the simple `.cs` class and I don not know why there is no way to use that statement.

Comment: I'm not sure HTTP is a good idea to make this simple transfer, because HTTP is not really a P2P protocol. Either you use IIS or any lightweight HTTP server or you use TCP, which is simpler in your case. However, even if you used HTTP, you would still have the Dispatcher problem if the HTTP request is ran in another thread. Here is a way to get the Dispatcher reference from anywhere in the app in Windows 8 Phone : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153801/how-to-get-dispatcher-in-non-ui-code-windows-phone-8

Comment: @gretro I need dispatcher in WPF(sender) in Windows Phone(receiver) it works fine.